# Git committing all changed, not just stagged changes after git add -p

Tags: git, commit

I am trying to get a partial change committed in git, and it seems to be doing what I would expect up until the actual commit, where unstaged changes get added to the commit.

Basically, I am staging partial changes using the `git add -p` command, but after I run `git commit` the staged and unstaged changes are committed.

What I am seeing:
I run `git add -p fileName`
Then `git status` shows:

```
on branch testBranch
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   fileName

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   fileName

Untracked files:
```

looks good to me.

I then do `git commit` and again when typing the commit message I see `Changes to be committed` and `Changes not staged for commit` as expected, both listing `fileName`.

However, after the commit, I see that the staged and unstaged changes to the file were committed.

Comment: How, precisely, do you make the commit? (i.e., what command line command do you use and what Git hooks do you have in place?)

Comment: The exact commit command is `git commit` (no `-a` tag). I think you may have helped me solve what's going on. I did not know that git hooks are a thing. I see that this project uses Husky and has a bunch of stuff in the `./.git/hooks/` directory. Not sure which one is messing with my commit, but that is the likely culprit. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, in this case I suspect a hook that doesn't respect the staged-vs-not-staged distinctions, and just runs roughshod over all your careful work.